Does the order of factor levels matter in a linear mixed effects model?
I'm running a linear mixed effects model using glmer in R and I have a question about the order of factor levels.
My dataset includes two factors:
data$interventions with levels c("m1", "f1", "m2", "f2")
data$group with levels c("controls", "subjects")
The model I'm using is:
model <- glmer(response ~ intervention * group + (1 | ID),
    data = data, family = binomial)

Do I need to change the order of levels for each variable, or is setting the levels once sufficient? I understand the interpretation of results might differ based on the reference levels, but does it affect the model fitting or the results beyond interpretation?

Unless either

you have a very large data set and a somewhat numerically unstable problem; or
you are doing something fancy (like setting the off-diagonal elements of a random-effects covariance matrix to zero — not a possibility in this case because your random-effect is scalar (intercept-only), so the covariance 'matrix' is 1x1)

then the order of the levels (and hence the contrasts that are used in fitting the model) should have no effect on the overall model fit.
For what it's worth, your question and the corresponding answer are not specific to linear mixed models. Since the part you're asking about is entirely in the fixed effect component of the model, you could have asked this question about linear (lm) or generalized linear (glm) models and the answer would be the same.
